# Send email on trigger failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, triggers, django-mssql

I have successfully configured and able to sent email using 'Database mail' on SQL server 2008 R2 by calling msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail stored procedure.
And I can catch the failure of a query in a trigger by putting it in try-catch block.

But What I need to do is, Send an email when a trigger fail to execute a query. But I can not execute above stored procedure within the catch block. It gave me following error.

```
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 64
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is there any other way to send email on trigger failure?
Or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger failure will always cause a transaction rollback and as such it cannot do any transactional operation, like calling `sp_send_dbmail`. One trick is to leverage custom profiler trace events, since they are sent on a standalone transaction:

```
create queue q;
create service sq 
    on queue q
    ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification]);
go

create event notification trace_user_0
    on server 
    for TRC_USER_CONFIGURABLE
    to service N'sq', N'current database';
go


create procedure usp_sq
as
begin

    declare @dh uniqueidentifier, 
        @mt sysname, 
        @mb varbinary(max),
        @mx xml;

    begin transaction

    receive top(1) 
        @dh = conversation_handle,
        @mt = message_type_name,
        @mb = message_body
        from q;

    if @mt = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/EventNotification'
    begin
        set @mx = cast(@mb as xml);

        declare @eventText nvarchar(4000);
        select @eventText = @mx.value (N'(//EVENT_INSTANCE/TextData)[1]', N'nvarchar(4000)');

        exec sp_send_dbmail @subject = 'Error in trigger', @body = @eventText;

    end
    else if @mt in (
        N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error', 
        N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
    begin
        end conversation @dh;
    end

    commit

end
go

alter queue q with activation (
    status = on,
    max_queue_readers = 1,
    execute as = 'owner',
    procedure_name = 'usp_sq');
go

create table MyTable (a int);
go

create trigger MyTrigger 
    on MyTable 
    after insert
as
begin try
    if rand() > 0.5
        raiserror (N'Something horrible happend in this trigger!', 16,1);
end try
begin catch
    declare @error_message nvarchar(256) = cast(error_message() as nvarchar(256));
    exec sp_trace_generateevent 82, @error_message;
end catch
go

insert into MyTable (a) values (1);
insert into MyTable (a) values (2);
insert into MyTable (a) values (3);
insert into MyTable (a) values (4);
insert into MyTable (a) values (5);
insert into MyTable (a) values (6);
go
```